# Relay - set variable before query

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, graphql

I'm currently working on a page that displays the status of a certain set of "tasks" for a specific user. To fetch the data, I have the following Relay container:

```js
export default Relay.createContainer(TaskReview, {
  initialVariables: {
    limit: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
    studentId: null,
  },
  fragments: {
    task: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Task {
        id,
        title,
        instruction,
        end_date,
        taskDataList(first: $limit, type: "subTasks", member: $studentId) {
          edges {
            node {
              id,
              answer,
              completion_date,
            }
          }
        },
        ...
```

To define which user I want to get data from, I use:

```js
componentWillMount = () => {
  let {relay} = this.props;
  relay.setVariables({
    studentId: this.props.member.id
  });
}
```

However, the problem here is that the query is first executed with `null` as defined in `initialVariables`. My backend implementation has it so that if the `studentId` is NULL, then it returns the data for all members.

The result is that the above query executes twice, the first time with all members, and the second time with the given `memberId`.

This messes up with other things within my `componentWillUpdate`. Is there anyway I can pass this variable and only get the data for that member on the first query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Prime your app with these initial conditions by passing your variable down through the route.

```js
class TaskReviewRoute extends Relay.Route {
  static paramDefinitions = {
    studentId: {required: true},
  };
  static queries = {
    task: () => Relay.QL`query { ... }`,
  };
  static routeName = 'TaskReviewRoute';
}

<Relay.RootContainer
  Container={TaskReview}
  route={new TaskReviewRoute({studentId: '123'})}
/>
```

Comment: Could you explain more about your answer, how this is going to solve the OP's problem? At the initial load, the studentId will be null, so, the request sends the null value to the back-end to fetch data. That's causing the problem.

Comment: If you pass `studentId` to the Relay container through the route as I've described above, and _remove_ the `componentWillMount` logic, then `studentId` will be non-null from the start. Think of `initialVariables` as a placeholder/default in case a value is not passed down from the parent as props (eg. by `Relay.RootContainer` owing to the presence of the route param described above).

Comment: what if the `studentId` isn't know upfront and can't be passed to the initializer of the route? I have a situation where a value is passed through the `params` of the router so I need another way to do this

Comment: I'd have to see your router code to advise you in detail, but the basic premise is to re-render the RootContainer every time the route params change, constructing and passing a new TaskReviewRoute. Presuming that `params` is in scope and coming from your router: `new TaskReviewRoute({studentId: params.studentId})`.

Comment: All in all, I must be missing something. You've said that you don't have the `studentId` up front, but at the same time you're pulling the `member.id` out of `this.props`, which implies that you must certainly have it up front. I think we need to see more code.